# VBA script for auto resizing of controls/subforms in MS Access 2003 forms?

Tags: ms-access

Since Access 2003 doesn't have the control anchoring functionality as exists in 2007, I was wondering if anyone has or is aware of some VBA script, or a freeware control, that can give this functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know of no exact duplication of the 2007 functionality in 2003. There are multiple components for resolution independence (resizing the controls on a form based on the users monitor resolution) and for resizing with the form resize event (such as http://www.fmsinc.com/products/components/ControlTour/resize.htm). None that I'm aware of quite replicate the 2007 experience, but a similar question (and code to handle it) can be found here: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Microsoft/Development/MS_Access/Q_23662850.html

Personally, I just handled the resize event myself. The easiest way is to do so is to create the form in the minimum size you wish to support, and then record the base positions and widths (either in a table or as form scoped constants). From there you can resize using:

```
resizeRatio = currentFormWidth / baseFormWidth

control.left = baseLeft * resizeRatio
control.width = baseWidth * resizeRatio
```

The advantage to doing this yourself is that over time you evolve it, with things such as keeping the labels on the left side the same width but expanding the fields to the right (this is done by not resizing the labels at all, and subtracting the end of the labels area off from the width of the form before applying the position and width changes, such as):

```
resizeRatio = (currentFormWidth - labelsAreaWidth) / (baseFormWidth - labelsAreaWidth)

control.left = (baseLeft - labelsAreaWidth) * resizeRatio + labelsAreaWidth
control.width = baseWidth * resizeRatio
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone come looking for 2007 or higher like - 2010, 2013, 2016 version. Here is the answer.

The font size will not automatically change based on screen resolution in any version of Access, but starting with **Microsoft Access 2007** you can use new properties of controls to make them **stretch, shrink or move** based on the size of a form (described [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/make-controls-stretch-shrink-or-move-as-you-resize-a-form-HA010253986.aspx))

Answer (score 1):

Try using the VBA code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40965025/2363207) answer to see if it gives you what you want. When the form is resized, all the controls and the text on the form will be proportionally resized too so that it looks the same no matter what size the window is, or what the user has their monitor resolution set to.