# Auto-Resize Form and Contents in Ms-Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, screen-resolution, ms-access-2000

**Background:**

I am creating an application in Ms-Access that is to be launched on a multi-user platform - This means many screens and many different resolutions etc.

**Question:**

Is it possible to have my application that automatically adjusts to the right size of the screen/resolution and the font size to be proportional to that of the % increased or decreased?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805877/how-to-auto-center-objects-in-a-form-in-access-2007/15808638#15808638), yes, you can use the `On Resize` event of a form to move controls around, change the size of subforms, and perform other similar operations. Those adjustments are applied to each individual object, so the coding would be somewhat tedious and a bit "fussy", but it can be done (at least to some extent).

Comment: Seems to be what I need just about. I had a play with this on a simple form but hopefully I can integrate this with my system! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The font size will not automatically change based on screen resolution in any version of Access, but starting with **Microsoft Access 2007** you can use new properties of controls to make them **stretch, shrink or move** based on the size of a form (described [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/make-controls-stretch-shrink-or-move-as-you-resize-a-form-HA010253986.aspx))

Comment: Thank you for your reply... unfortunately we are only on Access 2000. I know, don't judge! :) but once we upgrade I will take your solution into account!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the VBA code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40965025/2363207) answer to see if it gives you what you want. It works basically the way that Gord Thompson recommended. When the form is resized, all the controls and the text on the form will be proportionally resized too so that it looks the same no matter what size the window is, or what the user has their monitor resolution set to.